# The A to Z of setting up a Linux box for secure local hosting

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, php, ssh, centos

I am in the process of reinstalling the OS on a machine that will be used to host a couple of applications for our business. The applications will be local only; access from external clients will be via VPN only.

The prior setup used a hosting control panel (Plesk) for most of the admin, and I was looking at using another similar piece of software for the reinstall - but I figured I should finally learn how it all works. I can do most of the things the software would do for me, but I am unclear on the symbiosis of it all. This is all an attempt to further distance myself from the land of [Configuration Programmer/Programmer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349378/new-programming-jargon-you-coined/2373608#2373608), if at all possible.

I can't find a full walkthrough anywhere for what I'm looking for, so I thought I'd put up this question, and if people can help me on the way I will edit this with the answers, and document my progress/pitfalls. Hopefully someday this will help someone down the line.

### The details:

- CentOS 5.5 x86_64
- httpd: Apache/2.2.3
- MySQL: 5.0.77 (to be upgraded)
- PHP: 5.1 (to be upgraded)

### The requirements:

- SECURITY!!

  - Secure file transfer
  - Secure client access (SSL Certs and CA)
  - Secure data storage
  - Secure connection to another local machine (MySQL)
- Virtualhosts/multiple subdomains
- Local email would be nice, but not critical

### The Steps:

**[Download the latest CentOS DVD-iso](http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5/isos/x86_64/) (torrent worked great for me).**

---

**Install CentOS:**
While going through the install, I checked the Server Components option thinking I was going to be using another Plesk-like admin. In hindsight, considering I've decided to try to go my own way, this probably wasn't the best idea.

---

**Basic config:**
Setup users, networking/IP address, etc. Yum update/upgrade.

---

**Upgrade PHP/MySQL:**
To upgrade PHP and MySQL to the latest versions, I had to look to another repo outside CentOS. IUS looks great and I'm happy I found it!

**Add IUS repository to our package manager**

```
cd /tmp
wget http://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/stable/Redhat/5/x86_64/epel-release-1-1.ius.el5.noarch.rpm
rpm -Uvh epel-release-1-1.ius.el5.noarch.rpm
wget http://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/stable/Redhat/5/x86_64/ius-release-1-4.ius.el5.noarch.rpm
rpm -Uvh ius-release-1-4.ius.el5.noarch.rpm
yum list | grep -w \.ius\. # list all the packages in the IUS repository; use this to find PHP/MySQL version and libraries you want to install
```

**Remove old version of PHP and install newer version from IUS**

```
rpm -qa | grep php # to list all of the installed php packages we want to remove
yum shell  # open an interactive yum shell
remove php-common php-mysql php-cli #remove installed PHP components
install php53 php53-mysql php53-cli php53-common #add packages you want
transaction solve #important!! checks for dependencies
transaction run #important!! does the actual installation of packages.
[control+d] #exit yum shell
php -v
PHP 5.3.2 (cli) (built: Apr  6 2010 18:13:45)
```

**Upgrade MySQL from IUS repository**

```
/etc/init.d/mysqld stop
rpm -qa | grep mysql # to see installed mysql packages
yum shell
remove mysql mysql-server #remove installed MySQL components
install mysql51 mysql51-server mysql51-devel
transaction solve #important!! checks for dependencies
transaction run #important!! does the actual installation of packages.
[control+d] #exit yum shell
service mysqld start

mysql -v
Server version: 5.1.42-ius Distributed by The IUS Community Project
```

Upgrade instructions courtesy of IUS wiki: http://wiki.iuscommunity.org/Doc/ClientUsageGuide.

---

**Install rssh (restricted shell) to provide `scp` and `sftp` access, without allowing `ssh` login**

```
cd /tmp
wget http://dag.wieers.com/rpm/packages/rssh/rssh-2.3.2-1.2.el5.rf.x86_64.rpm
rpm -ivh rssh-2.3.2-1.2.el5.rf.x86_64.rpm
useradd -m -d /home/dev -s /usr/bin/rssh dev
passwd dev
```

Edit `/etc/rssh.conf` to grant access to SFTP to rssh users.

```
vi /etc/rssh.conf
```

Uncomment or add:

```
allowscp
allowsftp
```

This allows me to connect to the machine via SFTP protocol in Transmit (my FTP program of choice; I'm sure it's similar with other FTP applications).

rssh instructions appropriated (with appreciation!) from http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-unix-restrict-shell-access-with-rssh.html.

---

**Set up virtual interfaces**

```
ifconfig eth1:1 192.168.1.3 up #start up the virtual interface
cd /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/
cp ifcfg-eth1 ifcfg-eth1:1 #copy default script and match name to our virtual interface
vi ifcfg-eth1:1 #modify eth1:1 script
```

> #ifcfg-eth1:1 | modify so it looks like this:
>   DEVICE=eth1:1
>   IPADDR=192.168.1.3
>   NETMASK=255.255.255.0
>   NETWORK=192.168.1.0
>   ONBOOT=yes
>   NAME=eth1:1

Add more Virtual interfaces as needed by repeating. Because of the `ONBOOT=yes` line in the ifcfg-eth1:1 file, this interface will be brought up when the system boots, or the network starts/restarts.

```
service network restart
```

> Shutting down interface eth0:                              [  OK  ]
>   Shutting down interface eth1:                              [  OK  ]
>   Shutting down loopback interface:                          [  OK  ]
>   Bringing up loopback interface:                            [  OK  ]
>   Bringing up interface eth0:                                [  OK  ]
>   Bringing up interface eth1:                                [  OK  ]

```
ping 192.168.1.3
```

> 64 bytes from 192.168.1.3: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.105 ms

---

**Virtualhosts**

In the rssh section above I added a user to use for SFTP. In this users' home directory, I created a folder called 'https'. This is where the documents for this site will live, so I need to add a virtualhost that will point to it. I will use the above virtual interface for this site (herein called dev.site.local).

```
vi /etc/http/conf/httpd.conf
```

Add the following to the end of httpd.conf:

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.3:80>  
    ServerAdmin dev@site.local  
    DocumentRoot /home/dev/https  
    ServerName dev.site.local  
    ErrorLog /home/dev/logs/error_log  
    TransferLog /home/dev/logs/access_log  
</VirtualHost>
```

I put a dummy index.html file in the https directory just to check everything out. I tried browsing to it, and was met with permission denied errors. The logs only gave an obscure reference to what was going on:

> [Mon May 17 14:57:11 2010] [error] [client 192.168.1.100] (13)Permission denied: access to /index.html denied

I tried chmod 777 et. al., but to no avail. Turns out, I needed to chmod+x the https directory and its' parent directories.

```
chmod +x /home
chmod +x /home/dev
chmod +x /home/dev/https
```

This solved that problem.

---

**DNS**

I'm handling DNS via our local Windows Server 2003 box. However, the CentOS documentation for BIND can be found here: http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/ch-bind.html

---

**SSL**

To get SSL working, I changed the following in httpd.conf:

```
NameVirtualHost 192.168.1.3:443 #make sure this line is in httpd.conf 

<VirtualHost 192.168.1.3:443>  #change port to 443
    ServerAdmin dev@site.local  
    DocumentRoot /home/dev/https  
    ServerName dev.site.local  
    ErrorLog /home/dev/logs/error_log  
    TransferLog /home/dev/logs/access_log  
</VirtualHost>
```

<strike>Unfortunately, I keep getting (Error code: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long) errors when trying to access a page with SSL.</strike> As JamesHannah gracefully [pointed out below](https://serverfault.com/questions/142383/set-up-linux-box-for-hosting-a-z/142777#142777), I had not set up the locations of the certs in httpd.conf, and thusly was getting the page thrown at the broswer as the cert making the browser balk.

So first, I needed to set up a [CA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority) and make certificate files. I found a great (if old) walkthrough on the process here: http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/284.

Here are the relevant steps I took from that article:

```
mkdir /home/CA
cd /home/CA/
mkdir newcerts private
echo '01' > serial
touch index.txt #this and the above command are for the database that will keep track of certs
```

Create an `openssl.cnf` file in the `/home/CA/` dir and edit it per the walkthrough linked above. (For reference, my finished openssl.cnf file looked like this: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=hnZDij4T)

```
openssl req -new -x509 -extensions v3_ca -keyout private/cakey.pem -out cacert.pem -days 3650 -config ./openssl.cnf #this creates the cacert.pem which gets distributed and imported to the browser(s)
```

Modified `openssl.cnf` again per walkthrough instructions.

```
#generates certificate request, and key.pem which I renamed dev.key.pem.
openssl req -sha1 -new -nodes -out dev.req.pem -config ./openssl.cnf
```

Modified `openssl.cnf` again per walkthrough instructions.

```
#create and sign certificate.
openssl ca -out dev.cert.pem -md sha1 -config ./openssl.cnf -infiles dev.req.pem
```

### IMPORTANT!

#### Move the files and reference them from httpd.conf in the new location

```
cp dev.cert.pem /home/dev/certs/cert.pem
cp dev.key.pem /home/certs/key.pem
```

I updated httpd.conf to reflect the certs and turn SSLEngine on:

```
NameVirtualHost 192.168.1.3:443 

<VirtualHost 192.168.1.3:443>
    ServerAdmin dev@site.local  
    DocumentRoot /home/dev/https  
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /home/dev/certs/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/dev/certs/key.pem
    ServerName dev.site.local
    ErrorLog /home/dev/logs/error_log
    TransferLog /home/dev/logs/access_log
</VirtualHost>
```

Put the CA cert.pem in a web-accessible place, and downloaded/imported it into my browser. Now I can visit https://dev.site.local with no errors or warnings.

---

And this is where I'm at. I will keep editing this as I make progress. Any tips on how to configure SSL email, and/or configuring secure connection to another Box that will be the MySQL server would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand why do you need the virtual network interfaces?

Comment: @Milan because I will have multiple domains/subdomains on this machine. In order to use VirtualHost and SSL Each domain/subdomain will need to have its' own IP address. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/ssl/ssl_faq.html#vhosts

Comment: Looks like a waste of IP addresses to me, but ok. Alternatively, you could use different TCP/IP ports for each domain - all on single IP. That way the web server is less dependent on system configuration.

Comment: @Milan:Since the setup is local only, I have the luxury of way more available IP addresses than I'll ever need. Setting up additional interfaces, I've found, is a rather quick and painless process comparatively. If I were setting up this system for public use, thanks to Apache2.2.x and TLS upgrades, VirtualHost seems to work better with SSL: http://serverfault.com/questions/109766/ssl-site-not-using-the-correct-ip-in-apache-and-ubuntu/109782#109782

Comment: I did not consider that POV. Agreed.

Comment: Would highly recommend http://koltsoff.com/pub/securing-centos/ - a very educational walkthrough on securing CentOS (most of which is easily applicable to other distros) - it doesn't cover the hosting, but everything in there should be understood and applied to any CentOS server that isn't behind a firewall you understand and control.

Answer (score 6):

This guide has a lot of answers about using SSL with Apache, tells you how to create a self-signed certificate, how to get a proper certificate from a recognized certificate authority (CA) and how to create your own, untrusted CA to create a full certificate. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/ssl/ssl_faq.html

As for virtual hosts and SSL, each host will need its own IP address or a dirtier solution is to host them on different ports, than the standard `:443` due to the nature of SSL certificates, name-based virtual hosting does not get along with SSL; which is why you need another method to differentiate; differing ports/IPs.

Setting up SSH is pretty easy, it should be running on your server, already. You will want to do a number of things to lock it down.

```
PermitRootLogin no
AllowGroups admins
PubkeyAuthentication yes
PermitEmptyPasswords no
PasswordAuthentication no
```

It can be added to your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to restrict remote root access, and remove password authentication, instead using public/private keypairs to log in.

To create your SSH keypair, you can use `puttygen` in Windows; http://putty.very.rulez.org/download.html or you can create the keypair in a Linux environment like so: `ssh-keygen -b 2048 -t RSA -f my_keypair`. This will create a `my_keypair` file and a `my_keypair.pub` file (only named for this example, I might suggest naming for your username or leaving off `-f`, and letting it generate `~/.ssh/id_rsa`).

Securely transfer `my_keypair` to your workstation, for future SSH access, this is the private key, you should not share it with anyone. Then, on the server, create `$HOME/.ssh` if it does not already exist, `mkdir ~/.ssh`, then copy the public key (`my_keypair.pub`) to `~/.ssh/`, if you already have `authorized_keys` in `~/.ssh` because you've done this for other things, you can do `cat my_keypair.pub >> authorized_keys` to append your public key, or `cp my_keypair.pub authorized_keys` if it doesn't exist.

Now run `chmod 700 ~/.ssh` and `chmod 644 ~/.ssh/my_keypair.pub ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` to set permissions. You can keep a copy of `my_keypair` in `~/.ssh/` for use when connecting to other hosts, but you should do `chmod 600 ~/.ssh/my_keypair` to make sure no one else can access it.

You will want to add a normal user account for yourself, and add yourself to a group other than `users`, like `admins` in my example.

You will probably also want to add your user or group to `/etc/sudoers` to enable `sudo` usage, if you haven't already. This is accomplished with the command `visudo` which is the only way you should edit this file. `visudo` runs error and syntax checking on your configuration before writing it out, preventing loss of `sudo` usage.

```
username ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

added to `/etc/sudoers` will allow `username` to run `sudo yum install blah` and will prompt you for your own password. This is handy in the event you have other administrators or temporary administrators, you don't need to share the root password.

Comment: If you create a keypair in windows from puttygen, be aware you have to change the format of the public key once you upload it to the server. I don't remember how but youtube it there's actually a video.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your SSL config is that you've not actually *enabled* SSL, you'd need the Apache directives for that:

```
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /path/to/cert.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/key.pem
```

Without this you'll get those record too long errors, it's because instead of the SSL headers your browser was expecting, it's getting instead just the unencrypted web page in a big chunk.

Comment: (without this, all you've created is a regular non-SSL vhost listening on port 443)

Answer (score 1):

MySQL from the original package supports SSL. To check your MySQL build, run

```
mysqladmin variables | grep ssl
```

You should find something like `have_ssl yes`. Set up options `ssl-ca`, `ssl-key` and `ssl-cert`.

Create user accounts with SSL requirements:

```
create user@host identified by 'password'
grant privilegelist on database.tables to user@host require ssl
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I forgot to mention, though, that I will also be storing files on the db server so it looks like stunnel will work better in this case.